# Search if a string matches with any regex of an array in Perl

Tags: regex, arrays, perl

I have an array containing some PCRE matching patterns (like "prefix_.*") and I'm comparing a string with all the patterns of the array.
Currently, I'm working with this code:

```
foreach (@matchingPatterns) {
    if ("$string" =~ "$_") {
        [do something]
    }
}
```

This code is working well but I'm sure that there is a prettier way to do that in Perl (without any loop?).

Am I wrong? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much scope for improvement here, but I'd be more liable to write something like one of the following:

```
for (@matchingPatterns) {
    next if $string !~ /$_/;
    # do something
}
```

or

```
for (grep { $string =~ /$_/ } @matchingPatterns) {
    # do something
}
```

...both of which at least save you a few lines of code.

Comment: While we're golfing anyway, `do_something for grep {$string =~ $_} @matchingPatterns;`